# Disable broken laptop keyboard in Windows 8

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, autohotkey, laptop-repair, device-manager

Is it possible to disable the internal Keyboard on my Laptop? I poured Tea over it and now the "M"-key is stuck.

I tried a lot and it is far too expensive to replace the keyboard on this old laptop.

I would rather just connect a USB Keyboard and disable the internal one.

I tried uninstalling it in the Manager, but it reinstalls immediately.

I also tried autohotkey to fix this:

```
; This script disables the broken "m" key and replaces the caps lock key with an m key
Capslock::m
m::return
```

But this copletely disables the  key also on the Capsloc key

Comment: Can you pop of the key cap and clean underneath? See [If a laptop keyboard key isn't working, should I pull it out and clean its base?](http://superuser.com/q/325928)

Comment: Possible dup of [trying to disable laptop keyboard using gpedit.msc](http://superuser.com/q/704994)